# 2nd order differential equation to first order

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Make use of vectors to re-write the following second order differential equation into a 1st order differential equation. (note: I do not need to solve it).

$$
2.1x^{-2} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 3e^{2x} y^4 \frac{dy}{dx} = -6y
$$

where $y = 4.2$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = -3.1$ when $x = 0.5$.

Im not sure were to begin any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See how I wrote what you have there for some tips on how to format. Also, please double check that I didn't make any mistakes, and correct them if you can.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for the formatting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to rewrite one second-order equation into two first-order ones is to establish a second function, and tie it in with what's already there. I am sure there are problems with incredibly clever functions to choose that just makes the problem immediately solvable, but the standard choice is $z = \frac{dy}{dx}$. That is one equation, and it allows you to rewrite the original equation to get rid of all those second derivatives:
$$
2.1x^{-2} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 3e^{2x} y^4 \frac{dy}{dx} = -6y\\
2.1x^{-2} \frac{dz}{dx} - 3e^{2x} y^4 z = -6y
$$
which gives the two differential equations
$$
\cases{\displaystyle\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{3}{2.1}x^2e^{2x}y^4 - \frac{6}{2.1}x^2y\\\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} = z\vphantom{\Bigg(}}
$$
also known as the first order vector differential equation
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(z, y) = \left(\frac{3}{2.1}x^2e^{2x}y^4 - \frac{6}{2.1}x^2y, z\right)
$$with initial value $(-3.1, 4.2)$ for $x = 0.5$.